# Recommendations for good books on bacterial genetics & molecular biology?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, bacteriology

I'm starting a new phase of my PhD soon, and am feeling very under-prepared with respect to my general bacteriology knowledge. I was recommended to read up on basic **bacterial** genetics and molecular biology.

All the textbooks which I am familiar with from my past (Molecular Biology of the Cell etc,) rarely go in depth on the bacteria side of things. I really want a text which focusses solely on bacteria, and nothing else - this seems relatively hard to find recommendations for. I have Googled and found a few, but it would be nice to hear some first hand accounts on what books people recommend.

Comment: Why not start with a microbiology text? They tend to be very strong on those subjects, by my fuzzy recollection.

Comment: @MaximilianPress thank you. Do you have any favourites?

Comment: Afraid I'm quite out of date on these texts. You can find some material online via searches (e.g. https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Microbiology/Book%3A_Microbiology_(Boundless)/7%3A_Microbial_Genetics), possibly some combo of "microbiology", "microbial genetics", "bacterial genetics" etc. will get you there.